# Finding reoccurring data in different years

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one table. In it I have customers, orders, and dates of the order. Let's pretend this is it:

```
Customer   Orders  Date
----       ----    ----
Smith        1     2012-02-18 11:22:29.000
John         1     2012-08-21 02:04:38.000
Jones        1     2013-01-02 03:23:12.000
Smith        1     2013-02-06 09:12:32.000
```

I want to find out which customers returned and placed orders in more than one year and how many orders they placed. So, did Smith order in 2012 and 2013? Yes. How many times during those two years? Twice.

The result would be something like:

```
Customer   Orders  
----       ---- 
Smith        2
```

I know how to count how many times an order was placed over the space of two years, but I don't know how to exclude people who only ordered in one year, not both.

```
SELECT 
    o.Customer, 
    COUNT(o.Orders) as Orders
FROM Order as o
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2014-01-01'
GROUP BY o.Customer
```

I did look around first but I only saw answers that pulled from two different tables and I got lost. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

```
 WITH A AS (
  SELECT Customer
     ,   Orders
     ,   Date
     ,   [Year] = Year(Date)
  FROM   [Order]
 )
 ,   B AS (
  SELECT Customer
     ,   Orders = SUM(A.Orders)
     ,   [Year]
  FROM   A
  GROUP BY  
         Customer
    ,    A.[Year]
)
,    Orders2012 AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM   B
  WHERE  B.[Year] = 2012
)
,    Orders2013 AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM   B
   WHERE  B.[Year] = 2013
)
SELECT   O12.Customer
     ,   Orders2012 = O12.Orders
     ,   Orders2013   O13.Orders
     ,   TotalOrders = O12.Orders + O13.Orders
FROM    Orders2012 O12
    JOIN Orders2013 O13
        ON O12.Customer = O13.Customer
```

By breaking it into small pieces of processing, it's (I hope) clear at every step what I'm doing.  All my SELECTs are simple.  My query is long, but it's easy to understand, extend, modify, or add another year to.

Answer (score 1):

Use HAVING clause.

```
SELECT 
    o.Customer, 
    COUNT(o.Orders) as Orders
FROM Order as o
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2014-01-01'
GROUP BY o.Customer
HAVING COUNT(o.Orders) > 1
```

If you are specifically looking for having orders in different years then here is the query

```
SELECT 
        o.Customer,  
        COUNT(o.Orders) as Orders
    FROM Orders as o
    WHERE Date BETWEEN '01-Jan-2012' AND '01-Jan-2014'
    GROUP BY o.Customer
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(Date)) > 1
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53033f/16)

Comment: Oh. That seems super obvious now. Thank you! I think I'm getting it. :)

Comment: This probably don't work on big data. because this query gonna return result even if the user make orders in one year, not in both 2012 and 2013. Maybe Ashley confused was and wanted query with counting orders in date range.

Comment: Yes, I do just want things that happen in **both years**, not just one. And I am sorting through hundreds of thousands of entries.

Comment: Improved the answer. Check the second query

Answer (score 0):

This will check that you have orders on DIFFERENT years.

```
SELECT 
    o.Customer, 
    COUNT(*) as Orders
FROM Order as o
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2014-01-01'
GROUP BY o.Customer
HAVING MIN(YEAR(o.Date)) <> MAX(YEAR(o.Date))
```

if your dates are not really just a year.

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f2d1/6), with a little bit different data, to see the difference in having clause.

Tip :
Don't use Order as a table name : this is a reserved keyword, will be source of confusion.

Comment: @GordonLinoff even with the sample data given ?

Comment: You have a good point.  I'm looking at the `where` clause.  The data does show `date` as simply the year.  However, your `where` clause would generate a syntax error with that data.  So, that is another problem.

Comment: My dates are dates _and_ time. I apologize. I made my example date too simple.
I'm still playing around with this trying to make it work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you're right on that point. Well now all seems clearer.

Comment: @Ashley edited the SqlFiddle also, with two orders for Jones in 2013

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm still experimenting with it but I'm sure I'll get it with this help. :)